# Error: /usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.6/../hadoop does not exist! Please set $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME to the root of your Hadoop installation

Tags: macos, hadoop, sqoop

I installed Hadoop on Mac using brew and then configured it. Then I installed Sqoop and when I try to run Sqoop I get the following error:

Error: /usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.6/../hadoop does not exist!
Please set $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME to the root of your Hadoop installation.

My Hadoop is running fine, I have even set the path to HADOOP_COMMON_HOME in both **~/.bash_profile** and **sqoop-env.sh**

Here is my sqoop env file:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 
2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or 
implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# included in all the hadoop scripts with source command
# should not be executable directly
# also should not be passed any arguments, since we need original $*

# Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.

#Set path to where bin/hadoop is available
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME= /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/bin
#Set path to where hadoop-*-core.jar is available
#export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=

#set the path to where bin/hbase is available
#export HBASE_HOME=

#Set the path to where bin/hive is available
#export HIVE_HOME=

#Set the path for where zookeper config dir is
#export ZOOCFGDIR=
```

Comment: Please show your sqoop env file and `ls $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME`

Comment: @cricket_007 Here

Comment: Please [edit] the question.. with *text*, not an image in an answer

Comment: Also, I don't even know if Sqoop supports Hadoop 3.x yet

Comment: @cricket_007 Done, Doesn't sqoop support Hadoop 3.0?

Comment: According to the Sqoop documentation, it is only been tested in Hadoop 2.x, and it is recommended version as per the installation User Guide. In any case, you should definitely remove the space after the equal sign... `HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=` . This makes the property not be set

Comment: @cricket_007 it’s still not working, same error.

Comment: I typically use Hortonworks installations... And the property there is `HADOOP_HOME`. (Replace /usr/hdp/ 
 with your own install location) https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_command-line-installation/content/set_up_sqoop_configuration.html

Comment: @cricket_007 Done, Still getting the same Error: /usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.6/../hadoop does not exist!
Please set $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME to the root of your Hadoop installation.

Comment: $ cd /usr/local
     $ ln -s Cellar/hadoop/3.3.0 hadoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done `brew install hadoop` previously to do some Spark things. I don't think I had to edit any configurations in Hadoop itself,

but `brew install sqoop` seemed to work out of the box for finding the Hadoop configuration. Not sure where you got your `sqoop-env.sh` from, but having just installed it, here is mine.

```
[jomoore@libexec] $ cat /usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.6/libexec/conf/sqoop-env.sh
export HADOOP_HOME="/usr/local"
export HBASE_HOME="/usr/local"
export HIVE_HOME="/usr/local"
export ZOOCFGDIR="/usr/local/etc/zookeeper"
```

And if we grep the location that it wants to find hadoop in... `$HADOOP_HOME/bin`

```
[jomoore@libexec] $ ls -l /usr/local/bin/ | grep hadoop
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jomoore  admin                     45 Mar 13 10:24 container-executor -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/bin/container-executor
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jomoore  admin                     33 Mar 13 10:24 hadoop -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/bin/hadoop
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jomoore  admin                     31 Mar 13 10:24 hdfs -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/bin/hdfs
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jomoore  admin                     33 Mar 13 10:24 mapred -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/bin/mapred
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jomoore  admin                     50 Mar 13 10:24 test-container-executor -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/bin/test-container-executor
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jomoore  admin                     31 Mar 13 10:24 yarn -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/bin/yarn
```

And since I don't have Accumulo, Hive, or Zookeeper installed, these other warnings are just noise.

```
[jomoore@libexec] $ sqoop
Warning: /usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.6/libexec/bin/../../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.6/libexec/bin/../../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.6/libexec/bin/../../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
ERROR: Cannot execute /usr/local/libexec/hadoop-config.sh.
```

That error at the end is actually looking for the file here, which probably shouldn't be at `libexec/libexec` anyway within the Brew package

```
$ find /usr/local/Cellar -name hadoop-config.sh
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/libexec/libexec/hadoop-config.sh
```

Comment: In my case /usr/local/hadoop softlink to Cellar/hadoop/3.3.0 was missing. 
     `$ cd /usr/local ; $ ln -s Cellar/hadoop/3.3.0 hadoop`

Comment: Hadoop 3.3.0 isn't a thing

Comment: @cricket_007 I have installed sqoop exactly like you and get the output of all the commands you mentioned same as yours. Still when I run `sqoop`, nothing happens. Just get warning as you get, nothing else. Same with sqoop-version

Comment: @Aditya I wouldnt recommend even installing it on a Mac. I typically use an edge node setup by a Hadoop administrator.. Or if testing locally, I use the HDP Sandbox